# How to import non standard elevation data in netlogo

Tags: import, netlogo, elevation

```
file-open "ElevationData.txt" ; my code for importing the data
; 

while [not file-at-end?]
  [
let next-x  file-read
let next-y  file-read
let next-elevation  file-read
ask patch next-x next-y [set elevation next-elevation]
  ]
file-close

let min-elevation min [elevation] of patches
let max-elevation max [elevation] of patches
ask patches [
set pcolor scale-color red elevation  min-elevation max-elevation

]
```

I think I have to transform the data to make it compatible! but how do I do this? I will include an image of the data I want to import from the text file:

[http://postimg.org/image/jb4uqphbn/ http://s21.postimg.org/dzpy5zv92/elevation.jpg](http://s21.postimg.org/dzpy5zv92/elevation.jpg)

Comment: Can you get your data in some standard GIS format? If so, then you ought to be able to use the GIS extension to read it.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look of the image of your data file, you either need to include logic to skip the header information in the file when reading and deal with the spaces or an easier approach might be transforming the datafile to a .CSV and reading it that way. Also the XY coordinates in your file need to be translated and scaled so they fit into your patch coordinate system.

Comment: Note that recent NetLogo versions include a CSV extension with primitives for reading CSV files.